# Double for loop over Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing a column of subreddits and another column containing authors who have commented in that subreddit. Here is a snapshot:

```
subreddit                                                         user
0xProject            [7878ayush, Mr_Yukon_C, NomChompsky92, PM_ME_Y...
100sexiest                                                   [T10rock]
100yearsago                                       [PM_ME_MII, Quisnam]
1022                           [MikuWaifuForLaifu, ghrshow, johnnymn1]
1200isjerky                             [Rhiann0n, Throwaway412160987]
1200isplenty         [18hourbruh, Bambi726, Cosmiicao, Gronky_Kongg...
1200isplentyketo                                             [yanqi83]
12ozmouse                                                     [ChBass]
12thMan                                      [8064r7, TxAg09, brb1515]
12winArenaLog                                                  [fnayr]
13ReasonsWhy                                    [SawRub, _mw8, morbs4]
13or30                                          [BOTS_RISE_UP, mmcjjc]
14ers                                                      [BuccoFan8]
1500isplenty                                                  [nnowak]
15SecondStories                               [DANKY-CHAN, NORMIESDIE]
18650masterrace                                               [Airazz]
18_19                [-888-, 3mb3r89, FuriousBiCurious, FusRohDoing...
1911                 [EuphoricaI, Frankshungry, SpicyMagnum23, cnw4...
195                                                 [RobDawg344, ooi_]
19KidsandCounting                  [Kmw134, Lvzv, mpr1011, runjanarun]
1P_LSD               [420jazz, A1M8E7, A_FABULOUS_PLUM, BS_work, EL...
2007oneclan                                                    [J_D_I]
2007scape            [-GrayMan-, -J-a-y-, -Maxy-, 07_Tank, 0ipopo, ...
2010sMusic                                                    [Vranak]
21savage                                                     [Uyghur1]
22lr                                                      [microphohn]
23andme              [Nimushiru, Pinuzzo, Pugmas, Sav1025, TOK715, ...
240sx                [I_am_a_Dan, SmackSmackk, jimmyjimmyjimmy_, pr...
24CarrotCraft                                                [pikaras]
24hoursupport        [GTALionKing, Hashi856, Moroax, SpankN, fuck_u...
                                           ...                        
youtubetv                                [ComLaw, P1_1310, kcamacho11]
yoyhammer             [Emicrania, Jbugman, RoninXiC, Sprionk, jonow83]
ypp                                                           [Loxcam]
ypsi                                                           [FLoaf]
ytp                                                         [Profsano]
yugijerk                                             [4sham, Exos_VII]
yugioh               [1001puppys, 6000j, 8512332158, A_fiSHy_fish, ...
yumenikki                                                      [ripa9]
yuri                 [COMMENTS_ON_NSFW_PIC, MikuxLuka401, Pikushibu...
yuri_jp                                                    [Pikushibu]
yuruyuri                    [ACG_Yuri, KirinoNakano, OSPFv3, SarahLia]
zagreb                                                      [jocus985]
zcoin                                                      [Fugazi007]
zec                  [Corm, GSXP, JASH_DOADELESS_, PSYKO_Inc, infinis]
zedmains             [BTZx2, EggyGG, Ryan_A121, ShacObama, Tryxi, m...
zelda                [01110111011000010111, Aura64, AzaraAybara, BA...
zen                  [ASAMANNAMMEDNIGEL, Cranky_Kong, Dhammakayaram...
zerocarb                            [BigBrain007, Manga-san, vicinius]
zetime                                                        [xrnzrx]
zfs                  [Emachina, bqq100, fryfrog, michio_kakus_hair,...
ziftrCOIN                                                      [GT712]
zoemains             [DrahaKka, OJSaucy, hahAAsuo, nysra, x3noPLEB,...
zombies                                             [carbon107, rjksn]
zomby                                                        [jwccs46]
zootopia             [BCRE8TVE, Bocaj1000, BunnyMakingAMark, Far414...
zumba                                                   [GabyArcoiris]
zyramains                                       [Dragonasaur, Shaiaan]
zyzz                                                            [Xayv]
```

I am trying to iterate over every subreddit and then iterate over every subreddit beneath that to find shared commenters.  The end goal is a dataframe containing subreddit 1, subreddit 2, and the number of shared commenters.

I can't even conceive of how to do this using apply, and not sure how to do a double for loop with pandas df's.

Is this the right idea?

```
for i in df2.index:
  subreddit = df2.get_value(i,'subreddit')
    for i+1 in df2.index:
      ...
```

Here's an example of input and intended output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subreddit': ['sub1', 'sub2', 'sub3', 'sub4'],
                   'user': [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'F', 'C'], ['F', 'E', 'D'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z']]})
```

Output for first subreddit:

```
subreddit_1 subreddit_2 shared_users
sub1    sub2    2
sub1    sub3    0
sub1    sub4    0
```

Comment: No, loops are never the right idea. This seems like a difficult problem given your data, can you reduce this to a [mcve]?

Comment: Can we have a bit more context on how this data is generated? Are usernames stored as an array of strings, or something else? Are you getting this by running a groupby("subreddit") on another dataframe? Are you pulling data from a json file? It could be that starting from the dataframe you described is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can get around using loops. This seems pretty similar to how you would calculate a correlation matrix, which uses loops in the [pandas documentation](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L5465-L5519). At least it's symmetric so you only have to compare half of them.

Instead of calculating a correlation, you want to find the number of elements that are shared between two lists `lst1` and `lst2` which is `len(set(lst1) &  set(lst2))`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'subreddit': ['sub1', 'sub2', 'sub3', 'sub4'],
                   'user': [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'F', 'C'], ['F', 'E', 'D'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z']]})

mat = df.user
cols = df.subreddit
idx = cols.copy()
K = len(cols)
correl = np.empty((K, K), dtype=int)
for i, ac in enumerate(mat):
    for j, bc in enumerate(mat):
        if i > j:
            continue

        c = len(set(ac) &  set(bc))
        correl[i, j] = c
        correl[j, i] = c

overlap_df = pd.DataFrame(correl, index=idx, columns=cols)

#subreddit  sub1  sub2  sub3  sub4
#subreddit                        
#sub1          3     2     0     0
#sub2          2     3     1     0
#sub3          0     1     3     0
#sub4          0     0     0     3
```

And if you want to get those smaller `DataFrames` then you just need a little bit of manipulation. For example:

```
overlap_df.index.name='subreddit_1'
overlap_df[['sub1']].stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'shared_users'})

  subreddit_1 subreddit  shared_users
0        sub1      sub1             3
1        sub2      sub1             2
2        sub3      sub1             0
3        sub4      sub1             1
```

Comment: Wow, this is incredible.  Cannot believe how quickly this runs.  Thank you

Comment: thanks so much for that second addition.  Was working on that for an hour, until I saw your code.  I was again resorting to double for loops!

Comment: @Parseltongue no problem! And if you want to remove the self columns, just subset where `subreddit_1 != subreddit`

Comment: Thanks! Quick question: Would I have to change "sub1" to whatever the parent subreddit is for each subreddit? e.g. If I wanted every pairwise combination, rather than just the pairwise combinations that include 'sub1', I'd need to do a for loop that iterates through each subreddit column in the original df, and replace 'sub1' with that looped value?

Comment: @Parseltongue  Yes, if you want a DataFrame for each pair-wise combination you will probably need a loop to generate all of them. In that case, it might just be better to change how `correl` is created to make the separate `df`s in that part. Personally, I think having the large `overlap_df` is useful since it contains all the information in one place, but perhaps it's too big and not really what you want in the end.